# Facebook Connect: intermittent: Bad Signed JSON signature

Tags: json, facebook, signature, signed

I'm using Facebook connect. Over 50% of registrations are getting a "Bad Signed JSON signature." error.  What causes this problem and how is it fixed?

Here is the code:

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

    // decode the data
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        header('location: /volunteerregistration?error=Facebook has failed to connect. Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256 Please register with Omprakash below. ');
        exit;
    }

    // check sig
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        header('location: /volunteerregistration?error=Facebook has failed to connect. Bad Signed JSON signature. Please register with Omprakash below.');
        exit;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can try to look at this [link](http://www.violato.net/blog/php/71-uncaught-curlexception-60-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-that-the-ca-cert-is-ok-when-implementing-facebook-connect)

Answer (score 1):

had same problem solved by checking given app_secret to api. I copied an invisible sign/character

Answer (score 0):

50% of registrations that you're doing with known good accounts....or 50% of registration on web site in the wild? If it's in the wild, I would assume it's failed hacking attempts...trying to find sites that don't have the extra `$sig !== $expected_sig` check as your secure site does.  :)

Comment: Its 50% in the wild, but when I test it, I sometimes get this error and sometimes don't. It has also been reported by known individuals who aren't hacking the site.

Comment: Ok, just checking.  I've had situations where I'm not getting the signed request. See: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7352182/page-tabs-signed-request-occasionally-not-populated

Answer (score -1):

I think this is could happened because your apache server doesn't support for CURL library.
Open your php.ini, find ";extension=php_curl.dll" and then remove ";" it means that your php CURL uncommented.